# Algorithm for polynomial multiplication (discrete math)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, polynomials

I have an algorithm in the course I'm currently studying, which is used to (modulo) multiply two polynomials. I've been trying to work out how it works for half an hour, but can't seem to get it right. The powerpoint doesn't give a name nor a description of how it works.

Does anyone recognize it, and could tell me how it should be used?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it works as follows. The black rows in the screenshot are the coefficients of the red polynomial mutliplied with one monomial from the blue polynomial and shifted to the left according to the power of $x$ in the monomial from the blue polynomial. In more detail: the first black row consists of the coefficients of $76$ times the red polynomial ($76x^0$ is the monomial of degree $0$ in the blue polynomial), this row is not shifted to the left. The second black row consists of the coefficients of $4x$ times the red polynomial ($4x^1$ is the monomial of degree 1 in the blue polynomial). This row is shifted one time to the left. And so on for the other black rows. The black rows are shifted to the left so that the coefficients of the same power of $x$ are aligned in vertical columns. So far, there's no reduction modulo $251$. We get the green row at the bottom by adding up the black columns (since one column contains all the coefficients of monomials with like powes of $x$) and reducing modulo $251$. That's indeed the desired polynomial. The theoretical reason why this works is that
$$
\begin{align}
\varphi:\ & \mathbb Z[x] \rightarrow (\mathbb Z\ mod\ 251)[x] \\
& a_nx^n+\cdots+a_0x^n \mapsto (a_n\ mod\ 251)x^n + \cdots (a_0\ mod\ 251)x^0
\end{align}
$$
is a ring homomorphism, in other words multiplication and addition of integer polynomials and reduction of the coefficients modulo 251 are interchangeable.

To me, the algorithm looks pretty straightforward, and I don't know of a special name for it.

Comment: I don't think there's a name for it, this is just standard polynomial division.